# Laptop GPU is reporting temperature of 511 degrees

Tags: laptop, gpu, temperature

My Toshiba Satellite S50-B is less than a year old and is reporting a GPU temp of 511 degrees celsius. Core 0 and 1 report around 25-35 degrees celsius. I detected this using speedfan. I noticed that my computer performance has become quite poor lately (especially while gaming), even after deleting any unnecessary files. Is it possible that performance is being throttled in an attempt to reduce heat?

Why might this be happening? Can the temperature sensor be recalibrated or is it gone for good?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Thanks for your responses everyone and I'm sorry for the late response - I assumed that I would receive email responses notifying me.

Upon downloading techpowergup GPU-Z, GPU temperature is now reported at a lowly and realistic 64 degrees celsius. Also, computer is running better after modifying some power options and re-enabling dynamic GPU management (it was disabled after installing windows 10 and reverting).

Thanks again!

Comment: Your GPU actually running at 511 Celsius is simply not possible.  The real temperature is obviously not being reported correctly by Speedfan I suggest using some other tool ( not Speedfan ) and update your question.  "Is it possible that performance is being throttled in an attempt to reduce heat?" You told us nothing about the hardware you have.  This cannot be answered without that information. Update your question with that information.

Comment: That is impossible. Your GPU and computer would melt if it was running at 511C. Have you checked your CPU utilization when things become "slow"?

Comment: Do you have any other means to tell what the GPU temperature is?  Have you tried GPU-Z from https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/ ? Can you post a screenshot from both speed fan and GPU-Z?

Comment: Have you verified the legitimatcy of speedfan? Often some programmes might not be programmed/calibrated for laptops

Comment: Could it be 51**.**1 C? As mentioned above, all soldered connections would have melted at ~185 C.

Comment: When the GPU is suspended, its controller may report 511 as an invalid number.

Answer (score 2):

I was fixing a Toshiba L50-B05D that according to Speccy, Open Hardware Monitor and SpeedFan the GPU was running at a stable 511 degrees celsius. After gazing blankly at the screen in disbelief, I installed the latest drivers from Toshiba's website. Without success I continued onto AMD's website and pulled in the drivers directly from them, which I was confident about.

I'm not sure why, but when I left the drivers in tact and uninstalled AMD's Gaming Evolved (raptr), the problem came back. I then reinstalled Gaming Evolved but removed it from startup and rebooted the laptop, just to see what happens right? Well sure enough 511 degree GPU... again. I ran raptr and watched the temp reading in Speccy drop from 511 degrees to 40. After enabling Gaming Evolved on startup again and rebooting the computer a few times it appeared to have done the trick, at least it did in this scenario - I hope that this can help someone else too.

Comment: I have a Lenovo notebook, and also see a 511C GPU temperature under speedfan. Open Hardware Monitor gives the same result. Clearly a software fault on the drivers